# updating emacs on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, updates

I tried updating my emacs (22.1) to a newer version with this command:

```
 $ sudo port -u upgrade emacs
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

and now `emacs --version` still returns '22', obviously meaning it has not been updated.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port -u upgrade emacs
```

Comment: Actually, for some reason, it didn't work: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1258856/ What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to have the MacPorts bin directory in your shell $PATH. Or use an absolute path.  `/opt/local/bin/emacs'  or `export SHELL=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH`.  Add that to your shell startup file.

Comment: http://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell

Comment: Er, make that `export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH`.  Sorry!

Comment: It is in my PATH. I just needed to restart the terminal. Thanks agaiN